# How to Verify a Fix to smartctl Error?

Tags: centos, hard-disk, xfs, smartctl, sata

My harddrive got some errors per `smartctl` short test result (see below).

Then, I just zero-ed out data on my disk first for privacy reason:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc1 bs=1M
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc2 bs=1M
```

And then, I repartitioned into 1 big partition, and then I tried to use xfs_repiar to fix the errors: `sudo xfs_repair /dev/sdc`; tho, at the end, it printed:

```
Sorry, could not find valid secondary superblock
Exiting now.
```

Then I ran `sudo smartctl -t short /dev/sdc`:

```
smartctl 7.0 2018-12-30 r4883 [x86_64-linux-5.17.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-18, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF OFFLINE IMMEDIATE AND SELF-TEST SECTION ===
Sending command: "Execute SMART Short self-test routine immediately in off-line mode".
Drive command "Execute SMART Short self-test routine immediately in off-line mode" successful.
Testing has begun.
Please wait 1 minutes for test to complete.
Test will complete after Wed Jan 25 19:17:48 2023

Use smartctl -X to abort test.
[hc@hclinux22 src]$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdc
smartctl 7.0 2018-12-30 r4883 [x86_64-linux-5.17.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-18, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     ST2000DM008-2FR102
Serial Number:    [masked off]
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0bf3bfc3b
Firmware Version: 0001
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Jan 25 19:16:53 2023 HKT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      ( 249) Self-test routine in progress...
                    90% of test remaining.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x73) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 198) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x30a5) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   100   053   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   098   097   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       688
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   099   099   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       2720
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   079   060   045    Pre-fail  Always       -       86398239
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1741 (180 187 0)
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       688
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       4501
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       12885098499
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   066   059   040    Old_age   Always       -       34 (Min/Max 20/34)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       24
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   079   079   000    Old_age   Always       -       42048
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   034   041   000    Old_age   Always       -       34 (0 17 0 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   100   064   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   098   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1272 (103 165 0)
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       8760463243
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       22589260799

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 4501 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 4501 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1727 hours (71 days + 23 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 53 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:38:29.788  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      01:38:29.778  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00      01:38:29.752  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      01:38:29.750  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 00      01:38:29.737  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

Error 4500 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1727 hours (71 days + 23 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 53 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:38:29.638  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      01:38:29.628  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00      01:38:29.602  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      01:38:29.600  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 00      01:38:29.588  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

Error 4499 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1727 hours (71 days + 23 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 53 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:38:29.481  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:38:27.087  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:38:23.902  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:38:23.008  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 40 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:38:23.008  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 4498 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1727 hours (71 days + 23 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 53 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:38:13.746  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      01:38:13.728  FLUSH CACHE EXT
  61 00 78 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:38:13.725  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 c0 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:38:13.724  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      01:38:13.715  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]

Error 4497 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1727 hours (71 days + 23 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 53 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:38:13.519  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 c0 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:38:13.519  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 40 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:38:13.519  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 d0 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:38:13.519  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 40 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:38:13.518  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Self-test routine in progress 90%      1741         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1739         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1737         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      1709         3894432032

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

The previous errors still remain there.

If the errors stay in "log" but have already been fixed, how can I verify?

If the errors above are indeed still there, how can I fix and then verify?  I don't care about the drive, but I want to see whether the errors can be fixed and then the disk remains "reliable".

Thanks!

============================

Update:

```
$ sudo parted /dev/sdc unit MiB print
Model: ATA ST2000DM008-2FR1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 1907729MiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start    End         Size        File system  Name  Flags
 1      1.00MiB  1907729MiB  1907728MiB  xfs
```

Yes, when I repartitioned after erasing sdc1 and sdc2, I created an xfs for that partition:

```
$ ll /dev/sdc2
ls: cannot access /dev/sdc2: No such file or directory
$ ll /dev/sdc1
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8, 33 Jan 25 19:46 /dev/sdc1
```

Comment: @Panki I thought my `dd` command wrote zero's to the entire partitions with a block size of 1MB not just the first MB.

Comment: With that amount of `Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   099   099   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       2720` I'd get rid of this drive. It's not healthy. It can die any moment.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov thanks for your tips.  I agree that not using the HD anymore is the best defense for my data.  Tho, I am not sure the reallocated sector count went up for some odd reason (e.g. the HD wasn't attached poperly?) rather than real permanent damage.  Hence, my post here is to find a way to verify.  Any tip?

Comment: No one knows but it's extremely unlikely that "the HD wasn't attached poperly". Kinda sad to see it malfunction after relatively few hours of work, 1741. My 1TB HDD with 45 thousand hours has zero reallocation sectors/events but then it's properly cooled.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, there is some sort of hardware error here. Check that all the cables are seated (and if it's USB that the port is delivering enough power for the drive):

> ```
> 188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       12885098499
> ```

Secondly, your disk has a faulty area and is (currently successfully) remapping sectors to its spares. Sooner or later, though, it's going to run out of spare sectors and you'll start to see errors in your data:

> ```
>   5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   099   099   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       2720
> ```

Now, let's look at what you've done in response.

1. Erased everything in `/dev/sdc1`, the first partition on the disk
2. Erased everything in `/dev/sdc2`, the second partition on the disk
3. Tried to fix an XFS filesystem that's not in a partition but taking up the entire disk `/dev/sdc`

If you've erased data in partitions 1 and 2 then there's no accessible data left. But if you've got a partition table then you're unlikely to have a filesystem (XFS or otherwise) on the disk outside that partition table. It's more likely that you've either erased the data and there's no filesystem left to fix, or maybe just possibly there's an XFS filesystem on `/dev/sdc3`.

In your updated question, the partition table shows just a single partition, `/dev/sdc1`. If what you have shown us is accurate this means that your earlier `dd` will have created a large file called `/dev/sdc2` - and because there was no bound on the file size you will have filled your `/dev` partition and `dd` should have reported this error. Use `ls -l /dev/sdc2` to check whether it is a file or a device, and if *and only if* it is a file then remove it with `rm /dev/sdc2`.

On the other hand if `/dev/sdc2` is listed as a device or is missing then the partition table you're showing us isn't the partition table you've described in the rest of the question.

Comment: yes, I erased `/dev/sdc1` and `/dev/sdc2` and recreated a large partition `/dev/sdc1`.